# Almost sure converges to a constant

Tags: probability-theory

I am relatively new to measure theory and would appreciate if anyone can help me with proving the following assertion. The following statement seems trivial. But I would like to see a formal proof of it or at least identify which existing result (theorem) can be used to show.

Claim:
If $X_n$  a r.v converges a.s to a deterministic quantity, say, $C$. 
Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}E[X_n]=C$.

Thanks

Comment: The claim is false. Try to find a counterexample. Hint: the dominate convergence theorem requires that there is a integrable r.v. that dominates the sequence.

Comment: oh!, okay. So just to clarify, if if we add the condition that $|X_n|< X$ for all n, where X is integrable r.v. Then by dominated convergence theorem would the above assertion be true?

Comment: Yes. And it would be also true if the limit of the $X_n$ is any random variable (not necessarily constant).

Answer (score 1):

Let $Y$ be uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$ and suppose $\displaystyle X_n = \begin{cases} n & \text{if }Y<1/n, \\ 0 & \text{if }Y>1/n. \end{cases}$

Then $\Pr\left( \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} X_n=0 \right) = 1$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\operatorname{E}X_n = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} 1 = 1 \ne 0$.

This can happen because $\operatorname{E}\sup\limits_n X_n = \infty$.

If $\operatorname{E} \sup\limits_n |X_n|<\infty$ then no such problem occurs.  As mentioned in the comments, the dominated converges theorem entails that.

**Proof that $\operatorname{E}\sup_n X_n = \infty$:**

Notice what happens if $\dfrac 1 {m+1} < Y <\dfrac 1 m$: The fact that $Y< \dfrac 1 m \vphantom{\dfrac\int{\displaystyle\int}}$ means that $X_1 = 1,\ X_2=2,\ X_3=3,\ \ldots,\ X_m=m$, and the fact that $1/(m+1)<Y$ means that $X_{m+1}=X_{m+2}= X_{m+3}=\cdots = 0$. So in that case, $\sup=m$.
$$
\Pr\left(\sup\limits_n X_n = m \right) = \Pr\left( \frac 1 {m+1} < Y < \frac 1 m \right) = \dfrac 1 m - \dfrac 1 {m+1}.
$$
Then we have
$$
\operatorname{E}\sup_n X_n = \sum_{m=1}^\infty m\Pr\left( \sup_n X_n = m \right) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty m\left( \frac 1 m - \frac 1 {m+1} \right) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \left( 1 - \frac m {m+1} \right).
$$
This series of positive terms must diverge to $\infty$ because its terms do not approach $0$.

(I find myself wondering whether there's some standard name in the literature for this particular probability distribution and whether it arises naturally somehow.)

Comment: Could you please elaborate how you got $E sup X_n=\infty$ ?

Comment: @Indrajit : I've added a proof to the answer. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: The term of the series does approach 0. But it deverges: it is the harmonic series